# How to route to resolve error pages using ui-router with correct url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

We are using the latest version of Angular and AngularUI Router

A user is on some page `/foo`. They click a link to navigate to `/bar`. The `bar` state defines a resolve function that fetches some data from the server. To handle failure cases we have a `$stateChangeError` handler that examines the error and takes you to the correct error page (eg 500, 403, 401 etc). When the user does encounter an error going to `/bar` they wind up on something like `/errors/500`. But, this isn't right. When you navigate to urls on the web and encounter an error the url you wind up on should be *the url you intended to go to*. ie if you encounter a 500 error going to `/bar` your location should be `/bar`.

Has anyone figured this out in `ui-router`? Things attempted:

- Building the target url using `toState` and `toParams` and then calling $location.url/path in the error handler after going to the error page. This re-runs the route and attempts to fetch the data again.
- Calling `history.replaceState` after going to the error page. This really seems to mess with ui-router and seems to trigger unexpected state changes.
- Just biting the bullet and using the error states, eg `/errors/500`. This breaks the back button. If you are landing on a page and the server is returning an error when trying to load it the error handler will change state to the error page, so when you hit the back button you're back to `/foo` and it tries to resolve again and hits an error again and takes you back to `/errors/500`.

Comment: Take a look at `location` flag mentioned in the documents, I guess if you set it to false, url does not change. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **very** interesting question, and I had my share of wondering how to do that correctly !

My take on this is to handle navigation statuses with a service attached to a main controller.

I do the following:

- Use [named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views), and define a root abstract state (to hold common views, such as error pages).
- Define a NavigationStatus service, with a status attribute. status can be an object formatted as you desire (Example: `{code:403, reason:'Nope ! No way !'}`)
- Have the NavigationStatus service attached to the Main controller, wrapping my entire page.
- Wrap my variable content (ui-view) in a conditional block (ng-if) bound to the navigation state registered, so that it can remove the content when an error occurs.
- Add other conditional blocks in a switch/case fashion, to display error statuses. These can be templatized, expecting your navigation status object to have a defined set of attributes, and use views from your root abstract state.
- On content retrieval, systematically push a success or error state to the NavigationStatus service. I typically do it in Controller, but I guess you could do it an a ui-router resolve promise as well. On success, my main ui-view gets displayed. On error, it's replaced by a friendly message, without changing the URL.

Hope that helps ! :)

PS : (I can come with a working example if you're interested, but right now I'm a bit too tired)

Answer (score 4):

What I did was create a few error states, such as:

```
        .state('notFound', {
            url: '/errors/404',
            template: '<h1>Not Found</h1>' 
        })
        .state('accessDenied', {
            url: '/errors/403',
            template: '<h1>Access Denied</h1>'          
        })
```

Then, when you are handling the error, add in the option to not update the location:

```
        $state.go('notFound', {}, {location: false});
```

This results in changing to the notFound state, but it doesn't update the browser address bar, so the user is still seeing the previous url as you desire.

Comment: This is what I was attempting to do, as it seems like the ideal solution, however if the error is being thrown from a resolve parameter, the state never changes, so `location: false` just causes the state to remain on the original state (/foo in the OP) with the new 404 state template.  At this point, hitting the browser back button navigates one page further back in the history than we want to go.